# Convert ColdFusion Date to Unix timestamp

Tags: coldfusion, unix-timestamp, cfml

How can I convert a ColdFusion date to Unix Timestamp?

```
myDate = DateAdd("m", -1, Now());
```

I would like to convert myDate to unix timestamp using ColdFusion

Thanks

Comment: There's a UDF for that at CFLib... getEpochTime(). https://cflib.org/udf/GetEpochTime

Comment: Do you want this to be the timestamp from your application server or from your database server? What version of CF? And how is this being used? If you're going to do date math, you want to make sure all of your dates are starting from the same source and same point. Or at least you know how to convert them to a useful point of reference.

Comment: Edit: On a geeky note, this also means that in a little over 18 years, a lot of computers are going to forget how to accurately track time. Y2K again in Y2K38. :-)

Comment: Also, to add to the fun, ColdFusion doesn't use `1970-01-01` as Epoch. It uses `1899-12-30`.  https://trycf.com/gist/a9852ba8f37c68b11898482cda0cc2a8/acf2018?theme=monokai

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just create the UNIX origin date, and do a DateDiff from then to now (or whatever your date variable is) in seconds.

```
<cfset startDate = createdatetime( '1970','01','01','00','00','00' )>  
<cfset datetimeNow = dateConvert( "local2Utc", now() )>
<cfset UnixStamp = datediff( 's', startdate, datetimeNow )>
```

Comment: What does it need to be 1970? I want to get the last 30 days. I mean, Now() - 30 days

Comment: The start date is always 1970 because that's the Unix Epoch - what a Unix timestamp is based on. If you want to just get the # of seconds in the last 30 days, or the Unix time of a date 30 days in the past, you can alter the variables above to do that.

Comment: Why only one dateConvert?

Comment: @Ageax Good question. Running the start date through that function does not change the final result. It is absolute.

Comment: @Ageax Also note that Unix Epoch is based on UTC, so don't need to convert it there. Note, too, that using `dateConvert("local2UTC",mydate)` will base the calculations on the time of the computer the application is running on (for instance Daylight Savings Time). Dates in computers get really "interesting". There's not really such a thing as `2019-08-19 12:42:33 PM`; the computer sees it as `1566218553`. Which makes date math easy, but "fun" sometimes.

Comment: @Shawn - True. I know it's *supposed* to be be based on utc, but ... I recall CF getting creative with some of the utc stuff. Thought it might be a fix for something :-) "Never mind. Carry on."

Answer (score 4):

Since CF stores DateTime objects as Java Date objects, this also works:

```
var unixStamp = int( now().getTime() / 1000 );
```

getTime() returns milliseconds, which is why I divided by 1000 and rounded using int().

So, specifically for the example in the OP:

```
var unixStamp = int( myDate.getTime() / 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfset unixStamp = int(getTickcount() / 1000) />
```

You can get the current value of the internal milliseconds timer, and divide that by `1000` to get the time in seconds. Optionally you can cast to an integer if you don't want a float.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/gettickcount.html